# pull of refresh in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I trying to do pull to refresh but the design I using no fulfill my supervisor. How to this kind pull to refresh in nativescript, now I using this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-pulltorefresh in my project, and I  have not have idea how to do it, can give some advise?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dinamically load item when needed can use **virtual-array** module.

[Link to documentation examples](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/virtual-array/HOW-TO.html)

[Link to documentation info](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/virtual-array/VirtualArray.html)

The idea is that you can createa observable **virtual array** which has initial size and also **loadSize** instance property. Then on **itemsLoadingEvent** you can control the loading of new resources.

```js
var array = new virtualArrayModule.VirtualArray(100);
array.loadSize = 15;
array.on(virtualArrayModule.VirtualArray.itemsLoadingEvent, function (args) {
    // Argument (args) is ItemsLoading.
    // args.index is start index of the page where the requested index is located.
    // args.count number of requested items.
    //
    // Note: Virtual array will divide total number of items to pages using "loadSize" property value. When you request an 
    // item at specific index the array will raise "itemsLoading" event with "ItemsLoading" argument index set to the first index of the requested page
    // and count set to number of items in this page. 
    //
    // Important: If you have already loaded items in the requested page the array will raise multiple times "itemsLoading" event to request 
    // all ranges of still not loaded items in this page. 
    var itemsToLoad = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < args.count; i++) {
        itemsToLoad.push(i + args.index);
    }
    array.load(args.index, itemsToLoad);
});
```

More advanced examples for this functionality you can find in this sample app [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-demos/tree/master/cuteness.io)